# How to commit code from VS Code to GitHub

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I want to use Visual Studio Code and Gitlens to commit or push code to the new repository from GitHub, but I can't find a good tutorial with user friendly approach about how to use Gitlens in order to commit code to GitHub.

I have installed Git, VS Code and Gitlens.

Comment: GitLens isn't a client, it just shows you metadata, but VSCode is already a git client: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/versioncontrol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that, you do not need Gitlens at all. Visual Studio Code has that funtionality builtin. All its capabilities are explained in the corresponding [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-support).